# What is the thought process for circuit making after seeing input and output of a matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

Here is an exercise (4.27) from Nielsen and Chuang and I found the answer (given in the figure below) online without any explanation. The question was to construct a circuit by seeing a matrix (given in the figure).

**So I want to know what should be the thought process after seeing the matrix?**

[image]

Comment: This [thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/procedures-and-intuition-for-designing-simple-quantum-circuits/12440#12440) that is about the same exercise might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This exercise has been asked about a few times: like [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/procedures-and-intuition-for-designing-simple-quantum-circuits/12440#12440) and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16115/partial-cyclic-permutation-with-only-toffoli-and-cnot-gates/23311#23311).

I had posted a ‘semi-mechanical’ way that essentially eliminates guessing: [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23311/19153).  The idea is to use the fact that any boolean function can be written as a boolean polynomial, and use the resulting polynomial to synthesize a circuit.

Answer (score 0):

First, your transformation is not correct. Imagine multiplying this matrix with $|1\rangle$, and the result would be $|2\rangle$ instead of $|7\rangle$.

Personally, I prefer the method provided in this [slide](https://www.slideshare.net/GM3D/nielsen-chuang4-32). I do not understand Japanese, but hopefully, I have gotten its general idea. Next, I will explain that idea with a detailed circuit drawing.

The circuit $U$ transforms the computational basis
$$|0\rangle\rightarrow|0\rangle\quad|1\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle\quad|2\rangle\rightarrow|3\rangle\quad|3\rangle\rightarrow|4\rangle\quad|4\rangle\rightarrow|5\rangle\quad|5\rangle\rightarrow|6\rangle\quad|6\rangle\rightarrow|7\rangle\quad|7\rangle\rightarrow|1\rangle$$
Let $P_{mn}$ represent $|m\rangle\leftrightarrow|n\rangle$. Then,
$$U=P_{12}P_{23}P_{34}P_{45}P_{56}P_{67}$$

We can implement each one based on their binary representation. Note that Toffoli=$P_{67}$, and the Fredkin gate in Exercise 4.25 is $P_{56}$.  Most $P$ here can be implemented similarly with either Toffoli or Fredkin.

$P_{34}$ is tricky, though. Nevertheless, we can replace it with $P_{35}P_{45}P_{35}$. To see that, we can verify with $|3\rangle\rightarrow|5\rangle\rightarrow|4\rangle\rightarrow|4\rangle$, $|4\rangle\rightarrow|4\rangle\rightarrow|5\rangle\rightarrow|3\rangle$, and $|5\rangle\rightarrow|4\rangle\rightarrow|3\rangle\rightarrow|5\rangle$.

The final circuit is

[image]

Although there are simpler circuits for this question, this idea is nice because it is general in some sense. Some theory probably says that any permutation can be decomposed into pair-wise permutations $P_{mn}$. So, maybe this method can also solve some other permutation problems.

Comment: Yes, it is known that any permutation can be decomposed into transpositions ($P_{mn}$ type permutations).  In fact, any permutation can be decomposed into simple transpositions ($P_{i,i+1}$).