# What is Qiskit's Transpiler method for unitary synthesis?

Tags: qiskit, gate-synthesis

As I could found in [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13826) how the *transpile* works in qiskit, I understood that transpile gets arbitrary Unitary gate $U$ and some set of basis gates as input, and produce some quantum circuit of $U$ implemented with those basis gates.

So, I understood this transpile process as some sort of 'synthesis' problem that has been shown in some literature, but I can't find which synthesis method does Qiskit implemented for their transpile process. Will there be any references or docs that I can refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `transpile` uses unitary synthesis methods. That's done by a transpiler pass called `UnitarySynthesis` (source code [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/transpiler/passes/synthesis/unitary_synthesis.py)). Depending on the size of the gate to synthesize it has different methods. For example, single-qubit gates are converted into Euler angle rotations by `qiskit.quantum_info.synthesis.OneQubitEulerDecomposer` (source code [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/quantum_info/synthesis/one_qubit_decompose.py)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.